# Eclipse CDT error parser: absolute path on different machine

Tags: eclipse, parsing, gcc, eclipse-cdt, build-system

I have a CDT project which I build using an external build tool on a remote build machine. The files are shared onto my local machine, which means that the path that a file has on the build machine and my local machine are quite different.

The knock-on effect of this is that the default gcc/g++ error parser can no longer work out the error location, because the error may say:

```
/home/builduser/path/to/file.cpp:12:34: error: some error reason
```

but on my local machine, it is:

```
/home/localuser/other/path/to/file.cpp
```

Therefore, the error parser knows there is an error, but the file won't be found.

I have worked around by making a new error parser with entries that mirror the default gcc/g++ ones, but with a prefix for the filename:

```
/home/localuser/other/(.*?):(\d+):(\d+:)?\s*(([Ee]rror)|(ERROR)): (.*)
```

such that the contents of group `$1` are a *relative* path to the file. This works, and I get my click-ability and annotations back, but it seems like a hack, and I'd have to do the same for each entry in the gcc/g++ parser to get the full benefit.

Is there a setting somewhere to perform a path mapping (like my Debug settings have for the debug symbols)?